# Possbile differences between azure accounts

Tags: azure-web-apps

I hope I got to the correct stack exchange forum with this. 
I have two azure webapps with the same plan, and the same code. One under a personal account which works well, and the other is under enterprise account and sometimes fails. 
This service's main job is something that takes much CPU rather than I/O. After propcessing, it downloads the desired output in chunks. The one that fails simply misses some chunks.

Any answers or references are mostly welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, there should be no difference between services under different accounts. Perhaps you have different configuration? Ex. different regions?

Comment: Please add at least information on _how_ it fails. Any error messages? Can you provide any of your actual configuration? Otherwise this is too broad to answer and it would be merely guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I have said how it fails. By not downloading some of the packages required. What other configurations are there other than region? (I'm checking the region option)